# Why does an index scan retrieve two rows when there should only be one?

Tags: postgresql, explain

In tinkering with `pgbench` and `EXPLAIN`, I found the following:

```
[root@fc26c91163dc /]# pgbench -i
100000 of 100000 tuples (100%) done (elapsed 0.21 s, remaining 0.00 s)
vacuuming...
creating primary keys...
done.
[root@fc26c91163dc /]# psql
psql (12.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# insert into pgbench_branches values (generate_series(2,100000),1,'');
INSERT 0 99999
postgres=# vacuum full analyze;
VACUUM
postgres=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM pgbench_accounts a JOIN pgbench_branches b ON (a.bid=b.bid) WHERE a.aid < 100;
                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Merge Join  (cost=15.01..16.64 rows=106 width=194) (actual time=0.114..0.323 rows=99 loops=1)
   Merge Cond: (b.bid = a.bid)
   ->  Index Scan using pgbench_branches_pkey on pgbench_branches b  (cost=0.29..4247.29 rows=100000 width=97) (actual time=0.013..0.016 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=14.71..14.98 rows=106 width=97) (actual time=0.091..0.098 rows=99 loops=1)
         Sort Key: a.bid
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 38kB
         ->  Index Scan using pgbench_accounts_pkey on pgbench_accounts a  (cost=0.29..11.15 rows=106 width=97) (actual time=0.008..0.038 rows=99 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (aid < 100)
 Planning Time: 0.690 ms
 Execution Time: 0.380 ms
(10 rows)
```

Notice `Index Scan using pgbench_branches_pkey...actual time=0.013..0.016 rows=2...`

There is only one distinct `bid` value in `pgbench_accounts`:

```
postgres=# select distinct bid from pgbench_accounts ;
 bid 
-----
   1
(1 row)
```

`bid` is a primary key in `pgbench_branches`:

```
postgres=# select * from pgbench_branches where bid = 1;
 bid | bbalance | filler 
-----+----------+--------
   1 |        0 | 
(1 row)
```

So why does the `Index Scan` produce `rows=2` instead of `rows=1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't know that the next row present in pgbench_branches has bid>1 until it reads the next row and sees that it has bid>1.  It might be able to infer it from the primary key constraint, but it isn't written to do that.

Comment: Thanks!  That makes total sense